# How can i Change the DOt in a JavaFx RadioButton?

Tags: css, colors, javafx, radio-button, fxml

Hello Stackeroverflowers,

i'd like to ask how can i change a RadioButton Dot?
I need to define 3 RadioButtons with 3 different Colors to show a state.
Do i have to work with Css? 
Would be perfect if anyone could tell me how can i realize that ?

A Example would be:

```
@FXML
public RadioButton redState = new RadioButton();
.
.
.
redState.setDotColor(red);
```

or in Fxml to define the Color static:

```
style="-fx-dot-color: rgb(255,0,0);"
```

I hope everyone understood my Plan.
It's only about colorize the Dot in a javafx RadioButton.

I'm thankfull for every Answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but try

```
redState.getStyleClass().add("red-radio-button");
```

(or do this in FXML if you prefer).

And then in an external css file

```
.red-radio-button .dot {
  -fx-mark-highlight-color: red ;
  -fx-mark-color: red ;
}
```